# Paramiko: Error with windows file paths when transfering file over SFTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm currently working a server-client setup in which I have two separate server scripts. One python script is responsible for running a SSH listener with Paramiko, and that script runs on one machine. I have another server script specifically acting as an SFTP server on another, separate machine, within the same range and subnet as the other one.

My client code is running on a windows 10 system. Both servers are running in unix environments (macOS and Ubuntu 16.04 respectively).

The SFTP server that I am running is aptly titled `sftpserver`, and is available at https://github.com/rspivak/sftpserver/.

The below code is actually the entirety of my `client.py` as it stands, minus the import statements.

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('testkey.key')

transport = paramiko.Transport(('192.168.1.116', 10000))
transport.connect(username='root', password='toor', pkey=key)

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.1.107', username='root', password='toor')
chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
chan.send("Hey man! I'm connected!")
print(chan.recv(1024))


def sftp(localpath, name):
    try:
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        sftp.put(localpath, '/root/uploads/' + name)
        sftp.close()
        transport.close()
        return "<+> Done uploading"

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)


while True:
    command = chan.recv(1024).decode()
    ipdb.set_trace() // <-- debugging purposes only
    if 'grab' in command:
        _, path, name = command.split(' ')
        chan.send(sftp(path, name))
    else:
        try:
            CMD = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
            chan.send(CMD)
        except Exception as e:
            chan.send(str(e))

client.close()
```

Executing the `grab` command in my script looks like this:

`grab C:\Users\xxx\testing.txt testing.txt`

Now, if I write a path exactly like that (with the back slashes), it will append a second back slash after each one. So, the path I supplied now looks like `C:\\Users\xxx\\testing.txt`, and this is what I imagine is causing me to receive `File not found` errors. Thanks to pdb I was able to find this issue, but I am unsure how to continue. In all honesty, I am completely unsure if this problem is paramiko related or if it's some weird python behavior that I haven't encountered yet.

Also, sorry for no stack trace. I'll try to obtain one if possible, but I'm a bit pressed for time right this second.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've edited my post to include the stack trace. I'm about to sit down with PDB and figure out the answer to your second question :) though I do believe that I am getting past the transport management bit because according to the logs on my sftp server, the client is able to connect, authenticate, and open a channel with the server. Also, thank you for the suggestion! I will take that into account. Honestly, I hadn't thought to do that, lol.

Comment: Since there aren't any answers posted as such (just comments), you're fine to make major edits that change the question. It's only when there's an answer that would be invalidated that major changes to a question are bad form. So please do edit to show the new code, the new exception, etc -- no need for edit markers, even; the goal should be making the question as consistent and readable as possible for someone who's never seen it before, as people who want to know the history can click on the link to view it.

Comment: With respect to the backslashes getting doubled -- two backslashes is Python's `repr()` form for one *literal* backslash, so while I haven't seen the details of where you're getting the string with the doubled-up backslashes from, it doesn't strike me as exceptionally likely to be a problem, but just a matter of print format (for example, `\t` is how a tab is written in a Python string literal, `\n` is syntax for a newline, etc; so backslashes need to be doubled to distinguish them from part of such an escape sequence). That said, does switching to forward slashes help?

Comment: (This is one of those places where Microsoft made things unnecessarily problematic by trying to not follow the rest of the world and stick with forward slashes for path separators).

Comment: ...you might also use a command-line sftp client to connect to your server and see what kinds of paths work with it that way.

Comment: From https://github.com/rspivak/sftpserver/blob/master/src/sftpserver/stub_sftp.py#L63, it looks like the server treats the current working directory as the root of what it shares, so if you start the server in `c:\Users\xxx` then it would just be `./testing.xxx`, or if you start the server in `c:` it would be `Users/xxx/testing.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the continued help on this. I really appreciate it. I have tried using forward slashes with no success. The sftpserver is running in an ubuntu 16.04 VM, while the client code that is connecting to it, and thus where the test file is stored, is a windows one, just to clarify.

Comment: Ahh -- that is indeed a useful point of clarification; I was under the impression the server was on Windows. To back up and make sure I've got everything straight -- what directory are you running the server in, which user are you running it as, and what's the exact path being sent over-the-wire? (If the server is run in `/root/uploads` -- and btw, with my security hat on, running code as root, or sharing `root`'s home directory over a network, is usually a bad idea -- then it would just be `./foo`, not `/root/uploads/foo`, that needs to be passed).